# MacBook pro 2017 shuts down randomly (shutdown cause 5)

Tags: shutdown

I have a 13" 2017 MacBook pro that shuts down randomly.
Checking the logs I only see

```
2023-01-25 18:21:20.028735+0200 0x2ce      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 5
```

I checked for previous questions about this problem and found that shutdown cause 5 is a normal shutdown initiated by the user.
I also tried rebooting into safe mode. The issue prevails in safe mode as well.

Comment: It is probably the battery being that it’s pushing  6 years old.  What does the capacity look like when you power it back up after a shut down?

Comment: hmm I actually suspected it is related to it. I replaced the battery 3 months ago. Maybe it is because it's not a genuine apple battery (at the lab they told me there are no genuine batteries for mac products at all)

Comment: It couild be a defective battery. You have to check battery status before and after shutdown.  Try [Coconut Battery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) to give you some visibility

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just downloaded it and check, no indication for defective battery I guess? only things immediately pops out is the age of the battery (2013??)
https://ibb.co/thg8285

Comment: That could mean a NOS (new old stock) or a refurb where they used an old battery mgmt board on some new cells. It’s impossible to know without a teardown.  Also keep in mind that nothing can accurately measure a battery’s capacity like an actual battery tester. Software just gives you a spot reading.  What reads good now might be bad in a few minutes.  Coconut can help you track things to get some insight.